# I get an error (parse error) when i want to write the according formula in a google apps script sheet

Tags: formula, spreadsheet

I get an parse error if i want to set this formula via apps script into a google sheet

```
cell.setFormula("=NORM.DIST(P16;P24;P25;WAHR)");
```

Comment: Quick guess: should `wahr` be `true`? You may want to read [ask] and [edit] your question to include the actual error message.

Comment: Hi halfelf, thanks for the advice. i struggled with the language of javascript. I put "true" in the script and after running the script i get "wahr" in the formula in the sheet.